# Euclidean distance between a point shapefile and a line or polygon boundary

Tags: r

I want to calculate the Euclidean distance between (2000) points scattered on an island and the shoreline. 
I have the points, a polygon of the island and also a polyline file of the coast in separate shapefiles. All files are georeferenced and all points are marked with x and y coordinates.

Is there a way to easily do this, preferably in a for loop so I get all the distances with a single code.

I already read that the package `mapstat` is useful, but I am somehow not able to install it.

Any tips will be welcome!

Answer (score 3):

You could use `gDistance` from the `rgeos` package:

```
library("rgeos")
line <- readWKT("LINESTRING(1 0, 0.2 0, 0 0.2, 0 1)")
pt <- readWKT("GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(POINT(1.1 0.1), POINT(0.2 0.2), POINT(0.1 1))")

class(pt)
# [1] "SpatialPoints"
# attr(,"package")
# "sp"
class(line)
# [1] "SpatialLines"
# attr(,"package")
# [1] "sp"


plot(pt, axes=TRUE, xlim=c(-0.1, 1.2))
plot(line, add=TRUE)
```

[image: plot]

```
# distances between the two geometries in the units of the current projection;
# use planar coordinates for euclidean distances;
# byid=TRUE calculate distance for every point

gDistance(pt, line, byid=TRUE)
#        1      2   3
# 1 0.1414 0.1414 0.1
```

Comment: I will try that, much appreciated!